# docker file for tomcat

Tags: docker, tomcat

I wrote one docker file for tomcat installation, the file is

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

RUN wget http://mirrors.fibergrid.in/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.34/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.34.tar.gz

RUN gzip apache-tomcat-8.5.34.tar.gz

ADD https://github.com/spagop/quickstart/raw/master/management-api-examples/mgmt-deploy-application/application/jboss-as-helloworld.war /apache-tomcat-8.5.34/*/webapps

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

And I built the above docker file by using

```
$ docker build -t tomacat -f docker file name .
```

And created the container by using above docker image, command is

```
$ docker run --name=tom1 -d -it -p 9090:8080 tomcat
```

After running the `docker run` container is up and running

But **tomcat server is not up and running in background**

I replaced the `catalina.sh` with `startup.sh` in `CMD` area and also i getting same problem

Please help me for resolving  problem

Comment: Curious, did you checkout the existing docker image for tomcat: https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat? Looking at the Dockerfile from upstream (https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/1383c5549ee60522e76b37667c38b4cddc8bbc6d/7/jre8/Dockerfile), looks like it's not as simple as copying the tar file. Also I don't see the startup.sh file being copied into the docker image.

Comment: Hi, can you please show docker logs output of the container?

also please show docker inspect of the container.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question, I did everything as stated and started a container. After that I accessed the tomcat through `HOST_IP:HOST_PORT` and I was able to access the Tomcat. The issue may be that you are not accessing the Tomcat correctly like HOST_IP is not correct.